# invalid header error using DataStax cassandra driver within docker

Tags: python, docker, cassandra, datastax

We have a python application which makes a connection to a cassandra cluster. The python application runs within docker and we are using the datastax driver to make an attempt to connect to our cassandra cluster. This is what we are getting:

```
ValueError('Invalid size in header: 0x0',)
```

Comment: Could you please post the full stack strace?

Comment: @MarcosViníciusdaSilva, you can find a more complete stack trace here, https://pastebin.com/7nsJMLTw

Comment: i am also able to telnet from my docker container to the cassandra node on port 9042

Comment: @MarcosViníciusdaSilva here is the DEBUG of the error to help more, https://pastebin.com/jTnBdtSM

Comment: this is fixed we had an incorrect version of the lz4 library in our docker builds it should have been lz4==0.10.1 and we had 0.9